# Why branch is not covered with rest parameters in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm currently trying to cover 100% of my function but I'm facing a branch not covered and it don't understand why it's not covered and even how to fix and cover it.

[test coverage result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZapH.png)

It tried many different tests but it didn't changed anything. I don't if the problems comes from me or Jest ?

**My function**

```js
export const removeProductInList = (state: IItems, action: IBasketRemoveProductAction) => {
    const {
        payload: { uuid },
    } = action;
    const { [uuid]: itemToRemove, ...restOfItems } = state;
    return restOfItems;
};
```

**My tests**

```
product1 = { id: 1 };
product2 = { id: 2 };
mockUuid1 = 'IdTest';
mockUuid2 = 'IdTest2';
mockItem1 = { product: product1, quantity: 1 };
mockItem2 = { product: product2, quantity: 1 };
mockListItems = {
      [mockUuid1]: mockItem1,
      [mockUuid2]: mockItem2,
};

it('should handle PRODUCT__REMOVE', () => {
        expect(removeProductInList({ [mockUuid1]: mockItem1 }, removeProduct(mockUuid1))).toEqual({});

        expect(removeProductInList(mockListItems, removeProduct(mockUuid1))).toEqual({ [mockUuid2]: mockItem2 });

        expect(removeProductInList({}, removeProduct('acac'))).toEqual({});
    });
```

I expect to cover all the function with my actual test.

My version of jest is `23.4.1`, just in case.

Comment: You might be tested it using `state` with only `uuid` prop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to specify the target `esnext` in your `tsConfig` file in  ts-jest.

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports =  {
 ...
 'ts-jest': {
   ....
   tsConfig: './tsconfig.json'),
},
```

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  ...,
  "target": "esnext",
}
```

Comment: thanks ! I was indeed suspecting a configuration problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to test the `removeProductList` with extra properties

```
expect(removeProductInList({ [mockUuid1]: mockItem1, extraProp: 'someValue' }, removeProduct(mockUuid1))).toEqual({});
```

Comment: I think that is what I did in that test no ? `expect(removeProductInList(mockListItems, removeProduct(mockUuid1))).toEqual({ [mockUuid2]: mockItem2 });`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed Nicolas' answer and edited babel.config.json as below and it worked. Thank you, Nicolas.

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"], 
    "targets": {"esmodules": true}         <-- added this line
}
```